# User has (or) is

Tags: grammar

> User has/is unable to Save the screen.
>
> User has/is unable to enter the decimal value in 'Temperature'.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I think that you should use **is** in your example sentences. There might be better formulations, depending on context. Telling more about the context might improve the quality of answers. Is it a software notification? Or part of an instruction for a piece of software?

Comment: "Unable" is an adjective, head of the adjectival phrase "unable to save the screen". I cannot think of any context in which "has" can be followed by an adjectival phrase: it must be the copula "is".

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage in this example would be **is**.

*User **is** unable to Save the Screen.*
*User **is** unable to enter the decimal value in 'Temperature'*

Although I'm not sure what you mean by:

> *Save the Screen*

So you may wish to re word this.

> User **is** unable to enter the decimal value in 'Temperature'

You may want to change this to *enter **a** decimal value* depending on what you are trying to say.

Comment: 'Has' is the singular form of 'have', and both are in present tense.

Comment: Fair point, removed that line and fleshed out a little more.

Answer (score 1):

"Is" is correct.

"Is" with an adjective indicates a state of being. For example, "Bob is tired." Bob presently is experiencing the state of being tired.

"Has" can mean "possesses". Like you can say, "Bob has the book." (It can also indicate a continuous tense, like "Bob has been eating." But that's not relevant here.)

In your example, the user is in a certain state: the state of being "unable". "The user IS unable." The user doesn't possess or own anything.

Sometimes you can use "has" almost interchangeably with "is" by shifting the sentence from describing a state to describing an object, that is, from using an adjective to using a noun. For example, "The user is able to save the screen." "The user has the ability to save the screen." Both sentences mean essentially the same thing, but in the first we used the adjective "able", and in the second we use the noun "ability". So in the first sentence we need "is" to indicate the user's state, while in the second we need "has" to indicate the user's "possessions". (I say "possessions" in quotes because obviously "ability" is not a physical object that you can hold in your hand, but grammatically it is treated as something that you own.)